# What is the right word to use in this sentence: "start looking at things beyond the ( ) of judgement/criticism"?

Tags: vocabulary

"Let's start looking at things beyond the ____ of judgement."

What I want to say is that, let's stop looking for shortcomings in the things we see, let's stop looking at parts (of things that we see) that we could criticize. Let's stop looking at things like a quizzer (or paper-marker) who is looking for mistakes in the answer written by their student in an exam. Let's stop listening to people in order to find parts (of what they are saying) on the basis of which we could judge the person, and start empathizing with them.

How do I say that?

Comment: Note: I am sorry if my way of asking the questions is weird. I just always get stuck in things like that when I am trying to say something. Most of the times when I want to say something, I don't say it because I don't know how to properly articulate it. For the times when I do say something, I have to ask questions like this. I hope it isn't against the policies of this site.

Comment: how about “beyond the *myopia* of judgement...

Comment: "strictures" or "confines" could be used, but they don't convey all the meaning of your main paragraph ... there would still be some explaining to do. There is an idiomatic phrase "rush to judgement" that might be appropriate.

Comment: Let’s stop being so judgemental and start looking at things *through their eyes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's start looking at things beyond the **strictures** of judgment.*

> stricture
>
> : something that closely restrains or limits :  restriction *moral strictures* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stricture)

Answer (score 1):

**"Let's start looking at things beyond the limits of judgement; let's empathize instead."**

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but is that a quotation?

Comment: @Solace No, I merely incorporated your choice of words. Also, I prefer the more modern spelling, **"judgment,"** but **"judgement"** is still quite acceptable.

Comment: The spelling "judgement" isn't considered less modern in those dialects where it is standard (eg, AusE), and where "judgement" is considered a North American variant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's stop looking at this with the **imperative** to judge.

> of vital importance; crucial.
>   "immediate action was imperative"
>   synonyms:   vitally important, of vital importance, all-important, vital, crucial, critical, essential, necessary, indispensable, urgent;

Answer (score 1):

Consider "beyond the **dictates** of juddgment."

> Definition: a guiding or governing principle, requirement; an
>   authoritative rule, prescription, or injunction; a code or set of
>   codes governing action or procedure.
>
> Examples:
>
> - to follow the dictates of one's conscience.
> - Facts are stubborn things. And whatever may be our wishes, our inclinations, or the dictates of our passions, they cannot alter the
>     state of facts and evidence.

Answer (score 0):

"Let's start looking at things beyond the **dark glass** of judgement."

[With a nod to "through a glass, darkly".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_Corinthians_13#.22Through_a_glass.2C_darkly.22)

Comment: This doesn't work; it would have to be "Let's start looking at things without using the dark glass of judgement."

Comment: Works for me as is; YMMV.

Comment: There being no other examples of this usage on Google, and the metaphor being the filter metaphor (the old hymn changes the focus with 'Or if he wishes, through it pass ... And then the heavens espy'), I'd say it's not my mileage that's varying.